# Identifying multiple date formats using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently learning regex and I have a series in which dates have various formats such as:

```
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

I wrote a regex match query to satisfy the non-string cases in the following format but the dates that are in between the sentence are coming out as false.

```
df.str.match('([0-9]{0,2})[/-]?([0-9]{0,2})[/-]?([0-9]{2,4})')
```

Almost all the dates will use ? as the day, month and year occur once or more times in the string, also the day and month may be 1 or 2 characters long. The year can also be 2-4 characters long.

Some of the working test cases:

```
03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):

6/18/85 Primary Care Doctor:
```

Not working:

```
sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Services: None

7 on 9/27/75 Audit C Score Current:
```

It isn't working whenever the dates are in the middle of the sentence.
I would just like to be guided towards what all I should improve in the regex as I am still new to it. I am also a bit confused as to where we place the ?, before or after as well as the {}.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a text mining assignment, is it? :) Sorry, this is too broad for SO, I am afraid. You need to match each pattern *separately*, so that none of the patterns could match the same string as another regex.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `df.str.match()` uses `re.match()` which searches for the regex at the beginning of the string, whereas `df.str.contains()` uses `re.search()` which searches for matches anywhere in the string.

See ["search() vs match()"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) in the python re documentation for a more thorough explanation.

Pandas documentation for additional detail:
[pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains).

Note that I have not inspected your regex in detail, but this should address the initial problem you were facing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to have something working perfectly, but here is my regex if you want to start from it :

```
(?!\s)([(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?]*[.|,| |-|\/]*\d{1,4}[st|nd|th]?)+
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/4sHkun/2).